# Coffeescript syntax from C#

Tags: c#, coffeescript

I've got a really annoying issue, I can't find enough help to write my C# Function in Coffescript..

So I kindly ask if anyone would like to offer some help, with the syntax..
I'm having trouble finding the correct syntax, for the conversion, from C# to Coffee-script..
If anyone can be so kind in giving me some pointers that would be great..

Here is the C# Function/Method..

```
var url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/?namedetails=0&addressdetails=1&q=odense&format=json&limit=1";

var url = tb_Url.Text;
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 })
{
    wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");   //that is the simple line!
    var itm = wc.DownloadString(url);
    var Data = itm;
}
```

I had a lot of trouble finding anything on proper structure & syntax for Coffeescript, even though I've read that it's similar to JavaScript, which is hard enough to use, this is 100 times harder for me..
As for the Coffescript this is as far as I got with help from google:

```
http = require('http')
sendRequest = require('request')

sendRequestFor: (address) ->
    requestUrl = address
    request = sendRequest.get(requestUrl, headers: {'User-Agent': 'other'})
return request
```

I'd like some pointers on how & why these don't return the same data..

Comment: I'm finding your code rather difficult to read - could you include an example input and the output this would generate? Are you trying to parse a specific JSON object?

Comment: I've narrowed done the issue, and changed the code snippets to reflect the http requests.. Json wasn't the issue..